# strange behavior of XamlReader.Load()?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've got a very strange issue while parsing an external XAML file. The pre-history is that I want to load an external XAML file with content to process. But I want to load as many different files as I want. That happens by unloading the old and loading the new one.

My issue is:
When I load a xaml the first time, everything is good, all as it should be.
But when I load the same xaml the second time, every entry of the object im Loading is there twice. If I run this again, every object is there three times and so on...

To debug the project yourself, download it [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58977729/Presentator.zip). The function starts at line 137 in the file "Control Panel.xaml.cs". I realy don't know what this is. Is it my fault or simply a bug? If yes, is there a workaround?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Load a xaml file and parse it
    /// </summary>
    public void LoadPresentation()
    {
        this.Title = "Control Panel - " + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(global.file);

        System.IO.FileStream XAML_file = new System.IO.FileStream(global.file, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        try
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(XAML_file);
            string dump = reader.ReadToEnd(); //This is only for debugging purposes because of the strange issue...
            XAML_file.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

            presentation = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(XAML_file);

            //Keys the resourceDictionary must have to be valid
            if (presentation["INDEX"] == null || presentation["MAIN_GRID"] == null || presentation["CONTAINER"] == null || presentation["LAYOUTLIST"] == null)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            //When this list is loaded, every item in it is there twice or three times or four... Why????
            TopicList Index = null;
            Index = (TopicList)presentation["INDEX"];

            for (int i = 0; i < topics.Count; )
            {
                topics.RemoveAt(i);
            }

            foreach (TopicListItem item in Index.Topics)
            {
                topics.Insert(item.TopicIndex, (Topic)presentation[item.ResourceKey]);
            }

            lv_topics.SelectedIndex = 0;
            selectedIndex = 0;
        }
        catch
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Failed to load XAML file \"" + global.file + "\"", "Parsing Error", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            presentation = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            XAML_file.Close();
        }
    }
```

Edit:

I have tried to serialize the object that was read from the XamlReader and in the output was nowhere any childelement... But if I pull the object out of the dictionary, the children are all there (duplicated and triplicated, but there).

I have already tried to clear the list over

```
topics.Clear();
```

and

```
topics=new ObservableCollection<TopicListItem>();
lv_topics.ItemsSource=topics;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Index.Topics.Clear()` after loading the `Topics` into your topics object. That appears to get rid of the duplication.

```
//When this list is loaded, every item in it is there twice or three times or four... Why???? 
TopicList Index = null; 
Index = (TopicList)presentation["INDEX"]; 

topics.Clear();

foreach (TopicListItem item in Index.Topics) 
{ 
    topics.Insert(item.TopicIndex, (Topic)presentation[item.ResourceKey]); 
} 

Index.Topics.Clear();        //Adding this will prevent the duplication
lv_topics.SelectedIndex = 0; 
selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Yes, that solved it, thanks. But why? I don't understand why those objects are linked together...

Comment: To answer you, I am not sure why. I played with your code for about an hour to determine what I did. I eliminated the XamlReader.Load it was bringing in the correct number of topics, I noticed that the extra topics appeared as soon as you cast your presentation to TopicList. I am guessing it has something to do with the Static declarations in your TopicList Type. You are setting it to null then reassigning it, I beleive it is then connecting back up with the old data.

Comment: But isn't a static DependencyProperty the usual way to handle Bindings? And if so, there shall be the topics which are displayed first shouldn't they? I've shown the bug to several other people and their final opinion was, that there is a bug in the .NET Framework. I'll try to reproduce this and to gather more information...

Comment: The reason I stated what I did was because the TopicList never gets cleared out. Try this example  `TopicList Index = new TopicList(); TopicList temp = new TopicList(); Index = (TopicList)presentation["INDEX"];`  You will notice that temp will get the same amount of items when you load the Xaml file into Index. They are linked to the same list.

Answer (score 0):

In the code post topics is not declared in LoadPresentation() so naturally it will have any prior values.

I know you said you tried topics=new ObservableCollection(); but please try again.  And put that IN LoadPresentation()

```
    public void LoadPresentation()
    {
        ObservableCollection<TopicListItem> topics = new ObservableCollection<TopicListItem>()
```

I would pass filename

```
    public void LoadPresentation(string fileName)
```

I get you may need to use topics outside LoadPresentation but this is debugging.  If you need topics outside the return it.

```
    public ObservableCollection<TopicListItem> LoadPresentation(string fileName)
```

If that does not fix it I would put a try catch block on the XAML_file.Close(); to see if something weird is not going on.

Comment: If you would have read the post to the end, you would have recognitzed that I have already tried to clear the list with other, common, methods.

Comment: Clearly you had not exhausted all options to clear as you had not tried Index.Topics.Clear().   And according your post you had not tried declaring topic IN LoadPresentation().

Comment: Ah ok. Now I know what you ment: to clear Index.Topics. Sorry, I didn't understand.